# magento admin :reset password email via php code

Tags: admin, password

I earlier posted question to get customer rest password via code and below code works fine:

```
$email='abc@gmail.com';

$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
                ->loadByEmail($email);
$customer->sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail();
```

But what if want to reset password of one of admins , how can I use above code to work ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to `reset password`  then 
first load `admin`

```
            $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('admin/user_collection');
            /** @var $collection Mage_Admin_Model_Resource_User_Collection */
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('email', $email);
            $collection->load(false);
```

`then  send a generate password`

```
if ($collection->getSize() > 0) {
                foreach ($collection as $item) {
                    $user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($item->getId());
                    if ($user->getId()) {
                        $newResetPasswordLinkToken = Mage::helper('admin')->generateResetPasswordLinkToken();
                        $user->changeResetPasswordLinkToken($newResetPasswordLinkToken);
                        $user->save();
                        $user->sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want how to work in php so u can easy to idea using see the code hear.

> app\code\core\Mage\Customer\controllers\AccountController.php

```
public function forgotPasswordPostAction()
```

U can [apply your module](http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/how-to-extend-magento-core-controller/)  and   [Overriding customer account controller.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350044/magento-overriding-customer-account-controller)